# Conveying 'notebook' (programming)

Tags: traduction, informatique, science, université

Mathematica notebook, Jupyter notebook...Can one use colloquially the word 'notebook' in French (programming context)? Should it better to use '[carnet](http://hebergement.u-psud.fr/l3papp/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/memo.pdf)'?

Comment: I use Jupyter regularly but I never translate 'notebook' when speaking about it with French speaking colleagues (only my opinion, others' may vary).

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Je comprends. En ce qui me concerne 'Notebook Jupyter' désigne quelque chose de très précis pour moi et pour ceux avec qui j'en parle. Je doute que quelqu'un qui ne connaisse rien au développement comprenne de quoi il s'agit, que l'on utilise 'cahier', 'bloc-notes' ou 'notebook'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notebook_(programmation) suggests:

- notebook
- calepin électronique
- calepin

Answer (score 2):

You can also use **bloc-notes**

[Source](https://www.developpez.com/actu/189299/L-environnement-de-developpement-web-JupyterLab-pour-creer-des-notebooks-est-disponible-en-version-beta-avec-la-possibilite-d-ajouter-des-extensions/)

Answer (score 1):

On trouve aussi [*cahier*](https://www.lemondeinformatique.fr/actualites/lire-comment-jupyter-notebook-facilite-l-analyse-de-donnees-74605.html) (lemondeinformatique.fr).

---

Dans une [thèse](https://pastel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-02120824/document) j'ai trouvé une définition accessible du *notebook* : « Un notebook est un document interactif qui permet de ré-exécuter simplement toutes les étapes d’une expérience afin d’obtenir ses résultats dynamiquement. Il est composé d’un noyau effectuant les calculs et de cellules de texte enrichies pouvant être affichées avec une mise en page avancée. ». Elle traite  aussi de l'application *Jupyter* :

> Jupyter est un projet proposant une suite d’outils libres pour
> l’informatique interactive et parallèle scientifique. Ce projet est
> une évolution du projet IPython qui a été étendu pour donner le projet
> Jupyter. Le Jupyter Notebook est le format de notebook fournit(sic) par le
> projet Jupyter combinant code, texte, images, expressions
> mathématiques et des fonctions interactives au sein d’un même document
> qui est encodé dans un format texte documenté. Ces notebooks peuvent
> être lancés dans des interfaces graphiques ou web qui offrent un rendu
> graphique et un contexte d’exécution commun par l’utilisation d’un
> noyau.

Je retiens le contexte des *outils pour l'informatique interactive et parallèle scientifique* et les *documents interactifs* associés, les *notebooks*. Avec le nom du type de *notebook* (Mathematica, Jupyter etc.), le terme *notebook* et toutes ses traductions possibles pour ce document interactif fonctionneront sans doute.